# Creating Dynamic Controller Names in C# with WinForms for TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

While working on a small app that pulls test cases, runs, and results from an SQL Server Database, I encountered a dilemma in my methodology for attempting to create dynamic controller names in a TableLayoutPanel in WinForms. I am creating the rows dynamically when the user chooses the particular test case, and from there the TableLayoutPanel will open another window with the test steps preloaded and two radio buttons to indicate whether or not the test passed.  My issue is that when I select one of the radio buttons on the right of the step, I get the same console read every single time.  I need to be able to determine which exact radio button the user has pressed so I can therefore determine what row it's in and subsequently what test either passed or failed.  My main code is as follows:

**FormManualTest.cs (section when adding to the TableLayoutPanel)**

```
private void addRowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs anotherEvent)
    {

        tableLayoutTest.RowStyles.Clear();  // Clear row styles to ensure a clean start when adding to the TableLayoutPanel

        List<RadioButton> listOfRadioControls = new List<RadioButton>(); // Create array of radio buttons
        List<UserCustomStep> listOfStepControls = new List<UserCustomStep>(); // Create array of custom controls

        for (int i = 0; i <  5; i++)
        {
            UserCustomStep step = new UserCustomStep(Counter, "Step: " + i + " Push the button to elicit a response.");  // Creates new user custom step control instance

            RadioButton pass = new RadioButton();
            pass.Text = "Pass";
            pass.AutoSize = true;

            RadioButton fail = new RadioButton();
            fail.Text = "Fail";
            fail.AutoSize = true;
            fail.Margin = new Padding(3,3,20,3);  // Needed to see the fail button without having to scroll over

            listOfStepControls.Add(step);  // Add step to UserCustomStep array

            listOfRadioControls.Add(pass);  // Add radio buttons to the RadioButton array
            listOfRadioControls.Add(fail);

            listOfRadioControls[i * 2].CheckedChanged += (s, e) => // Subscribes the pass radio button to listen for when a user has clicked on it
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pass " + i + " was clicked");
            };

            listOfRadioControls[(i * 2) + 1].CheckedChanged += (s, e) => // Subscribes the fail radio button to listen for when a user has clicked on it
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail " + i + " was clicked");
            };

            tableLayoutTest.Controls.Add(listOfStepControls[i], 0, i);  // Adds CustomStep to first column
            tableLayoutTest.Controls.Add(listOfRadioControls[i*2], 1, i);  // Adds Pass Radio Button to second column
            tableLayoutTest.Controls.Add(listOfRadioControls[(i * 2) + 1], 2, i); // Add Fail Raido Button to third column

            Counter++;  // Increment couter to add subsequent steps underneath the previous ones.

        }

    }
```

**Screenshots of App with Console Readout:**

**After Test Case Has Been Clicked and Radio Button Has Been Pressed**
(From clicking this I would expect the console to read "Pass 1 was clicked")
[image: Screenshot of App when Steps have been loaded in and Pass radio button has been clicked]

**Console Read:**

[image: Console Read]

**Click Fail Button:**
(I know from this image below that since the Pass button doesn't remain clicked I'm somehow using the same controller for all 5 of them)

[image: Fail Button Pressed]

**Console Read**

[image]

So from all of these issues that I've been presented with, I know that I'm somehow using the same controller for all 5 instances regardless of the fact that I'm storing everything in a controller array and grabbing from there.  The for loop will have to be converted to a for each loop later, but that still doesn't solve my issue.  I believe that if I could say something like:

```
RadioButton (pass+id) = new RadioButton();
```

or something similar while looping through to dynamically create the name for the controls, then each one would be a completely separate control and I could go from there.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I come from a heavy web background so my normal skills to remedy this in JS land aren't coming in handy as of right now.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property is optional, you don't need to specify it and it doesn't need to be unique. You can use property [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) for your own purpose (you can assign there ID or event instance of some object).

However you can also create your own control/usercontrol which encapsulate the whole row, and you can declare your own properties exactly for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I was using a Custom Controller for the first column with the "step" label and just ended up encapsulating the entire row with your suggestion.  Worked like a charm the first time around.  Thanks again!